# bind entity to get single record

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

How to fetch single entity record data please find the code below 
    binding in xml table.am doing like below

```
table in xml view 
<Table  items="{/dum}" id="table" width="auto">
```

When you can bind the url directly to the table:

If I give like below am getting all records.

```
 var url = "/myentity";
    var table = oView.byId("table");
    table.bindItems({
        path: url,
        template: table.getBindingInfo("items").template
    });
```

If I give var `url = "/myentity('srujan')";`
am not able to get particular  user data

```
HTTP request failed400,Bad Request,{"error":{"code":"005056A509B11EE1B9A8FEC11C23378E","message":{"lang":"en","value":"System query options '$orderby,$skip,$top,$skiptoken,$inlinecount' are not allowed in the requested URI"
```

Comment: Have you tried using bindElement with the absolute entity path?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the snippet that shows how bindElement ("binding" in the XML) it works for your case:

```js
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel({
    "Product(1)": {
      Price: 100,
      Name: "Product # 1"
    },
    Products: [{
      Price: 200,
      Name: "Product # 1"
    }, {
      Price: 500,
      Name: "Product # 2"
    }, {
      Price: 542,
      Name: "Product # 3"
    }]
  });

  sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModel);

  sap.ui.xmlfragment({
    fragmentContent: document.getElementById("table").textContent
  }).placeAt("content");
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <script src="https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js" id="sap-ui-bootstrap" data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal" data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"></script>
  <script id="table" type="sapui5/xml">
    <Table xmlns="sap.m" binding="{/Product(1)}">
      <columns>
        <Column>
          <Label text="Binding" />
        </Column>
        <Column>
          <Label text="Column 2" />
        </Column>
        <Column>
          <Label text="Column 3" />
        </Column>
      </columns>
      <items>
        <ColumnListItem>
          <Text text="/Products(1) on table" />
          <Text text="{Name}" />
          <Text text="{Price}" />
        </ColumnListItem>
        <ColumnListItem binding="{/Products/2}">
          <Text text="/Products/2 on item" />
          <Text text="{Name}" />
          <Text text="{Price}" />
        </ColumnListItem>
      </items>
    </Table>
  </script>
  <div id="content"></div>
</body>

</html>
```